# Fading Image transparency on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, image

I'm using some javascript for fading images: a gallery of images which fade from one to the next. Images can also have captions overlaid. The image behind the caption is slightly faded out, so the caption can be clearer seen:

```
background: #fff;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)"; /* IE 8 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75); /* Older IEs */
opacity: 0.75; /* Real browsers */
```

In Internet Explorer, however, you see the **next picture** behind the caption. This is not ideal. [Demo](http://filedump.xn--es-zka.info/fading/).

See here (screengrab), where under the caption the next image shows through:

[image: Next image fading through under caption.]

Note: This problem is seen in IE7, IE8, and in IE8 emulating IE7. It is, I am told, not seen in IE9, even when IE9 is used to emulate previous versions of IE. The emulator is obviously imperfect.

Comment: Also note it helps to say what version of IE, there are only 4 of them right now in the wild.

Comment: I've seen it in IE7 and 8. I imagine it's no better in IE6, but I've not checked. Have a glance at the demo.

Comment: @TRiG - I have looked at the demo in IE7, IE8, IE9 and Firefox 3.6 and they all look exactly the same as far as I can see. The image behind the caption is the same image that is currently displayed on the on the screen. I don't suppose you could include an image showing the problem for your end?

Comment: I'll try doing a screen grab. It would probably help to make things more obvious if the images were all the same shape, or had more contrasting colours.

Comment: @My Head Hurts, Screengrab added. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @TRiG: That looks like a funky bug in IEs rendering. We had stuff like that with IE 6 on some of our sites. There is nothing we could do about it. You can just trial & error yourself out of this as far as i can tell.

Comment: @elusive, What I'm doing right now is commenting out the `-ms-filter` and `filter` properties. This presents a solid white background in IE. Not ideal, but better than fadethrough. Interesting that it's not showing up for @My Head Hurts, though.

Comment: @TRiG - No problem. Thanks for the screen grab. Unfortunately I can't reproduce that error in my browser (using the same image to test). Are you using IE8 or IE9?

Comment: That's IE8. I don't actually have IE9. It looks the same if I change the browser mode to IE7.

Comment: Ok, I am using IE9. Maybe the browser modes are not as good in IE9. I will look at the code on the page and see if there is anything that can be deduced just from that.

Comment: @My Head Hurts. I'd imagine the modes aren't perfect. IE is hardly lugging around three completely independent rendering engines inside it. It'd be a security nightmare trying to keep them all patched. So when it's emulating an older version, it's probably just applying some tweaks to the current version, and that might not be a perfect emulation of what it's trying to do.

Comment: @My Head Hurts, I added a note about IE versions to the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

IE is unable to handle the `opacity`-property. You need to use a hack:

```
background: #fff;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)"; /* IE 8 */
filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* older IEs */
opacity: 0.75; /* modern browsers */
```

Note that those filters use a range from 0 to 100 rather than 0.0 to 1.0. Frameworks like jQuery do this for you, which is really handy if you're assigning styles dynamically.

Comment: @elusive - filter: alpha (...) works for IE8 and above, so you don't need the -ms-filter property. Or does the -ms-filter do something special?

Comment: @My Head Hurts: This is a workaround for some issues in Quirksmode and compatibility modes. You should add it to be safe. The order is important, too here.

Comment: I actually do have both of those in too. It was silly of me to not put the full CSS in the question. I'll add it. Do have a glance at the demo.

Comment: @elusive - Thanks, I did not know that. If the order is important, should the -ms-filter not come after the `filter:...` as the styles cascade or is the `"progid:..."` setting up a value within / for the following `filter`?

Comment: @My Head Hurts: You need to use the order stated in my example. Otherwise, IE 8 in IE 7 compatibility mode wont apply the opacity (do not ask me why that is).

Comment: @elusive - OK. I can understand that (why it is important when using the compatability mode).Thanks for the information and the explanations!